# How to display 1 to 100 numbers with using query

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I want to write a query to print numbers from 1 to 100 in MySQL and I can't seem to find any solution.
I tried a few things

```sql
with CTE as  
(  
 select 1 Number  
 union all  
 select Number +1 from CTE where Number<100  
)  

select *from CTE
```

But I don't think it works in MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then your current syntax is not far off, and might even work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (Number) AS (
    SELECT 1            -- base case returns 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1   -- recursive case returns 1 + previous value
    FROM cte
    WHERE Number < 100
)

SELECT Number
FROM cte
ORDER BY Number;
```

Recursive CTEs work by having a base case, which seeds one or more values, as well as a recursive case, which is an iteration on the previous values.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it is showing error                      Unknown column 'n' in 'field list'

Comment: Sorry, `n` was a typo for `Number`, please reload your page and try it again.

Comment: I'm really glad u helped i was gonna try while loop can u explain your query . It would really help.